# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adaptive_gridsampler.adaptive_gridsampler_cuda'

Tags: python, pre-trained-model, resuming-training

I want to retrain the code of this paper "Learned Image Downscaling for Upscaling using Content Adaptive Resampler", so I started by the inference, however when I run **run.py** I got this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adaptive_gridsampler.adaptive_gridsampler_cuda'
```

Knowing that the train.py of this paper is not available, I found many solutions to this problem such as:

```
Change floor to **floorf** at adaptive_gridsampler/adaptive_gridsampler_kernel.cu Line 49-54.
```

But to no avail